# Online Judge: Creating bunch of std::stacks

Tags: c++, memory-management

I came across this problem and was solving it. The problem is pretty straight forward. You would be given input set of PUSH and POP commands and you need to print the output for that appropriate stack.

```
Sample Input:
7
PUSH 1 100
PUSH 1 200
PUSH 2 300
PUSH 2 400
POP 2
POP 1
POP 2
Sample Output[Expected]:
400
200
300
```

In order to address this, I came up with the below idea. however, my result is not coming up as one would quite expect. I am getting lot of garbage values. Can you please help me out on this one please?. I have resolve this using Java. But the judge was not accpeting Java code. So, had to code this in C++. Any ideas as to what is missing here are most appreciated.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<stack>
#include<string>
#include<map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int,std::stack<int> > indexStackMap; // int->stack

    int noOfInstructions = 0;
    scanf( "%d", &noOfInstructions );

    for( int inx = 0; inx < noOfInstructions; ++inx )
    {
        char instruction[5];
        scanf("%s", &instruction );     

        int stackNumber = 0;
        scanf( "%d", &stackNumber );

        if( strcmp( instruction, "PUSH" ) == 0 )
        {            
            int stackValue = 0;
            scanf( "%d", &stackValue );

            std::map<int,std::stack<int> >::iterator intStackIter = indexStackMap.begin();

            if( indexStackMap.find( stackNumber ) == indexStackMap.end() )
            {
                // Element not in yet!.
                std::stack<int> *tempStack = new std::stack<int>();
                tempStack->push( stackValue );
                indexStackMap[ stackNumber ] = *tempStack;                
            }
            else
            {
                std::stack<int> & ref = intStackIter->second;
                ref.push( stackValue );
            }
        }
        else
        {
            std::map<int,std::stack<int> >::iterator intStackIter = indexStackMap.find( stackNumber );
            std::stack<int> & ref = intStackIter->second;
            ref.pop();
            printf( "%d\n", ref.top() );
        }
    }
    return  0;   
}
```

Thanks,
Pavan.

Edit: This solution of mine works correctly. But throws memory limit exceeded error from the judge. http://pastebin.com/hYuGgzp5

Edit: The following code resolve this issue.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<stack>
#include<string>
#include<map>

int main()
{
    std::map<int,std::stack<int> > indexStackMap; // int->stack

    int noOfInstructions = 0;
    scanf( "%d", &noOfInstructions );

    for( int inx = 0; inx < noOfInstructions; ++inx )
    {
        char instruction[5];
        scanf("%s", &instruction );     

        int stackNumber = 0;
        scanf( "%d", &stackNumber );

        if( strcmp( instruction, "PUSH" ) == 0 )
        {            
            int stackValue = 0;
            scanf( "%d", &stackValue );

            indexStackMap[stackNumber].push(stackValue);
        }
        else
        {
            std::map<int,std::stack<int> >::iterator intStackIter = indexStackMap.find( stackNumber );
            std::stack<int> & ref = intStackIter->second;
            printf( "%d\n", ref.top() );
            ref.pop();

        }
    }
    return  0;   
}
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @awesomeyi Code review site is not intended for finding bugs in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When popping for the stack, you are calling `stack::pop()` before looking at the value of `top()`. This needs to be the other way around because `pop()` removes the top element from the stack.

You also have a memory leak due to (unnecessary) `new` without matching `delete`.

By the way, to push a new element, you just need:

```
indexStackMap[stackNumber].push(stackValue);
```

instead of the whole `if` statement. This will add a new stack to the map if needed.

Comment: @internjay Thanks, it did it. I have updated to code and posted as an edit to this quesiton. But I was never aware of the below piece that could resolve my work. -> indexStackMap[stackNumber].push(stackValue);

So, is the STL intelligent enough to deal with cases like this?. I mean we are no supplying an instance of stack to the STL Map. Yet it is able to understand.

Comment: Ofcourse, this solution is still giving me a memory limit judge error, bt that is fine.